# XMI File Reading using Asp.net C# and show in tree view

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, xmi

How I can read XMI file in asp.net C# and show in tree view. XMI have different format with XML , I want to read XMI file data with following format in asp.net C#. Format for XMI given bellow. Can any one please suggest how I can read this format and convert this XMI to Tree format in C#

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
        <nickname exportedFromDifferentName="false"/>
    </xmi:Extension>
</xmi:Documentation>
<xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
    <projectProperties>
        <projectProperty name="author" value="Dell"/>
        <projectProperty name="description" value="test"/>
    </projectProperties>
    <ProjectOptions>
        <IDPositionRotation>
            <Positions>
                <Position id="BPTask" value="\u0004"/>
                <Position id="BPSubProcess" value="\u0004"/>
            </Positions>
            <Positions>
                <Rotation id="BPTask" value="\u0000"/>
                <Rotation id="BPSubProcess" value="\u0000"/>


            </Positions>
        </IDPositionRotation>

        <LanguageDataType>
            <LanguageDataTypeModel id="Java" name="Java">
                <DataType>boolean</DataType>
                <DataType>byte</DataType>

            </LanguageDataTypeModel>



            <LanguageDataTypeModel id="UML" name="UML">
                <DataType>boolean</DataType>
                <DataType>byte</DataType>


            </LanguageDataTypeModel>
        </LanguageDataType>

        <GeneralOptions confirmSubLevelIdWithDot="true"/>

        <ModelQualityOptions enableModelQualityChecking="false"/>
        <OfficeExchangeOptions generateBlankModel="false" generateTableOfContent="true" insertPageBreak="true"/>
        <ORMOptions decimalPrecision="19" decimalScale="0" exportCommentToDatabase="true" formattedSQL="false" generateAssociationWithAttribute="false" generateDiagramFromORMWizards="true" getterSetterVisibility="\u0000" idGeneratorType="native" mappingFileColumnOrder="\u0000" numericToClassType="\u0000" quoteSQLIdentifier="\u0000" recreateShapeWhenSync="false" syncToClassDiagramAttributeName="\u0001" syncToClassDiagramAttributeNamePrefix="" syncToClassDiagramAttributeNameSuffix="" syncToClassDiagramClassName="\u0000" syncToClassDiagramClassNamePrefix="" syncToClassDiagramClassNameSuffix="" syncToERDColumnName="\u0000" syncToERDColumnNamePrefix="" syncToERDColumnNameSuffix="" syncToERDTableName="\u0004" syncToERDTableNamePrefix="" syncToERDTableNameSuffix="" synchronizeDefaultValueToColumn="false" synchronizeName="\u0002" tablePerSubclassFKMapping="\u0000" upperCaseSQL="true" useDefaultDecimal="true" wrappingServletRequest="\u0001"/>
        <RequirementDiagramOptions defaultWrapMember="false" showAttributes="\u0001" supportHTMLAttribute="false"/>
        <StateCodeEngineOptions autoCreateInitialStateInStateDiagram="true" autoCreateTransitionMethods="true" defaultInitialStateLocationX="-1" defaultInitialStateLocationY="-1" generateDebugMessage="false" generateSample="true" generateTryCatch="true" language="\u0000" regenerateTransitionMethods="false" syncTransitionMethods="true"/>
        <WarningOptions createORMClassInDefaultPackage="true"/>
        <PORepository>
            <POUserIDFormats>
                <POUserIDFormat digits="2" guid="false" id="s_eav6qAUEBg4gV9" lastNumericValue="0" modelType="BPMNElement" prefix="BP" suffix=""/>
                <POUserIDFormat digits="2" guid="false" id="s_eav6qAUEBg4gV." lastNumericValue="0" modelType="Actor" prefix="AC" suffix=""/>

            </POUserIDFormats>
        </PORepository>
    </ProjectOptions>
</xmi:Extension>
<uml:Model name="Online Bookshop" xmi:id="ineav6qAUEBg4gOG">
    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
        <vpumlChildModels>
            <vpumlModel id="mneav6qAUEBg4gOR" modelType="WSDLContainer">
                <properties>
                    <property name="name" type="string" value="WSDLContainer"/>
                    <property name="modelType" type="string" value="WSDLContainer"/>
                </properties>
                <vpumlChildModelRefs>
                    <modelRef value="uneav6qAUEBg4gOS"/>
                </vpumlChildModelRefs>

            </vpumlModel>


            <vpumlModel id="jneav6qAUEBg4gPL" modelType="PMPriorityContainer">
                <properties>
                    <property name="name" type="string" value=""/>
                    <property name="modelType" type="string" value="PMPriorityContainer"/>
                </properties>
                <vpumlChildModelRefs>
                    <modelRef value="jneav6qAUEBg4gPM"/>
                    <modelRef value="jneav6qAUEBg4gPN"/>
                    <modelRef value="jneav6qAUEBg4gPO"/>
                </vpumlChildModelRefs>
                <vpumlChildModels>
                    <vpumlModel id="jneav6qAUEBg4gPM" modelType="PMPriority">
                        <properties>
                            <property name="name" type="string" value="Low"/>
                            <property name="modelType" type="string" value="PMPriority"/>
                        </properties>
                    </vpumlModel>
                    <vpumlModel id="jneav6qAUEBg4gPN" modelType="PMPriority">
                        <properties>
                            <property name="name" type="string" value="Medium"/>
                            <property name="modelType" type="string" value="PMPriority"/>
                        </properties>
                    </vpumlModel>
                    <vpumlModel id="jneav6qAUEBg4gPO" modelType="PMPriority">
                        <properties>
                            <property name="name" type="string" value="High"/>
                            <property name="modelType" type="string" value="PMPriority"/>
                        </properties>
                    </vpumlModel>
                </vpumlChildModels>
            </vpumlModel>


        </vpumlChildModels>
    </xmi:Extension>
    <ownedMember name="UseCase" xmi:id="UseCase_UseCase_id" xmi:type="uml:Stereotype">
        <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
            <baseType value="UseCase"/>
            <taggedValueDefinitions>
                <taggedValueDefinition htmlValue="" id="hveav6qAUEBg4gVn" name="Level" type="2" value="">
                    <value value="Summary"/>
                    <value value="User"/>
                    <value value="Subfunction"/>
                </taggedValueDefinition>

                <taggedValueDefinition htmlValue="" id="pveav6qAUEBg4gVr" name="Preconditions" type="4" value=""/>
                <taggedValueDefinition htmlValue="" id="pveav6qAUEBg4gVs" name="Post-conditions" type="4" value=""/>

            </taggedValueDefinitions>
            <qualityScore value="-1"/>
        </xmi:Extension>
    </ownedMember>
    <ownedMember name="Case Story" xmi:id="UseCase_Case Story_id" xmi:type="uml:Stereotype">
        <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
            <baseType value="UseCase"/>
            <qualityScore value="-1"/>
        </xmi:Extension>
    </ownedMember>
    <ownedMember name="requirement" xmi:id="Requirement_requirement_id" xmi:type="uml:Stereotype">
        <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
            <baseType value="Requirement"/>
            <taggedValueDefinitions>

                <taggedValueDefinition htmlValue="" id="tfeav6qAUEBg4gV4" name="kind" type="2" value="">
                    <value value="Functional"/>
                    <value value="Performance"/>
                    <value value="Interface"/>
                </taggedValueDefinition>

            </taggedValueDefinitions>
            <qualityScore value="-1"/>
        </xmi:Extension>
    </ownedMember>
    <ownedMember xmi:type="uml:Collaboration">
        <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
            <dummyModel value="true"/>
        </xmi:Extension>
        <ownedBehavior name="Communication Diagram" xmi:id="..HGv6qAUEBg4gWI" xmi:type="uml:Interaction">
            <lifeline name="online book shop" represents="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ_represents" xmi:id="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ" xmi:type="uml:Lifeline">
                <lowerValue value="1" xmi:id="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ_multiplicity_lowerValue" xmi:type="uml:LiteralString"/>
                <upperValue value="*" xmi:id="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ_multiplicity_upperValue" xmi:type="uml:LiteralString"/>
                <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                    <active xmi:value="false"/>
                    <stopped xmi:value="false"/>
                    <multiObject xmi:value="false"/>
                    <lifeline/>
                    <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                </xmi:Extension>
                <coveredBy xmi:idref="auR_gGqAUEBg4gnk"/>
                <coveredBy xmi:idref="2E9_gGqAUEBg4gn6"/>

            </lifeline>
            <ownedConnector xmi:id="D_Fo_6qAUEBg4gk1" xmi:type="uml:Connector">
                <end role="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ" xmi:id="D_Fo_6qAUEBg4gk2" xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd">
                    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                        <modelType value="InteractionLifeLineLinkEnd"/>
                        <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                    </xmi:Extension>
                </end>


            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:id="Qa6Y_6qAUEBg4gmC" xmi:type="uml:Connector">
                <end role="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ" xmi:id="Qa6Y_6qAUEBg4gmD" xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd">
                    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                        <modelType value="InteractionLifeLineLinkEnd"/>
                        <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                    </xmi:Extension>
                </end>


                <ownedRule constrainedElement="n0XgQGqAUEBg4gsC" name="Order_complete" xmi:id="M792QGqAUEBg4gyr">
                    <specification body="self.order&gt;0" xmi:type="uml:OpaqueExpression"/>
                    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                        <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                    </xmi:Extension>
                </ownedRule>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:id="3CmY_6qAUEBg4gmI" xmi:type="uml:Connector">
                <end role="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ" xmi:id="3CmY_6qAUEBg4gmJ" xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd">
                    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                        <modelType value="InteractionLifeLineLinkEnd"/>
                        <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                    </xmi:Extension>
                </end>

                <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                    <modelType value="InteractionLifeLineLink"/>
                    <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                </xmi:Extension>
            </ownedConnector>
            <fragment covered="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ" message="auR_gGqAUEBg4gnj" xmi:id="auR_gGqAUEBg4gnk" xmi:type="uml:EventOccurrence">
                <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                    <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                </xmi:Extension>
            </fragment>

            <fragment covered="GypQ_6qAUEBg4ggf" message="2E9_gGqAUEBg4gn5" xmi:id="2E9_gGqAUEBg4gn7" xmi:type="uml:EventOccurrence">
                <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                    <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                </xmi:Extension>
            </fragment>
            <ownedConnector xmi:id="EzegQGqAUEBg4grB" xmi:type="uml:Connector">
                <end role="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ" xmi:id="EzegQGqAUEBg4grC" xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd">
                    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                        <modelType value="InteractionLifeLineLinkEnd"/>
                        <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                    </xmi:Extension>
                </end>

            </ownedConnector>


            <message connector="6jguv6qAUEBg4gce" name="find_books()" receiveEvent="wLguv6qAUEBg4gcn" sendEvent="wLguv6qAUEBg4gcm" xmi:id="wLguv6qAUEBg4gcl" xmi:type="uml:Message">
                <signature xmi:id="wLguv6qAUEBg4gcl_type" xmi:type="uml:Action"/>
                <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                    <returnValue name="" xmi:id="jtfQQGqAUEBg4gtR" xmi:type="uml:ReplyAction">
                        <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                            <iteration xmi:value="false"/>
                            <asynshronous xmi:value="false"/>
                            <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                        </xmi:Extension>
                    </returnValue>
                    <number xmi:value="1"/>
                    <asynshronous xmi:value="false"/>
                    <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                </xmi:Extension>
            </message>

            <ownedAttribute name="online book shop" xmi:id="ydguv6qAUEBg4gcZ_represents"/>
            <lifeline name="inventory" represents="mdyff6qAUEBg4ggL_represents" xmi:id="mdyff6qAUEBg4ggL" xmi:type="uml:Lifeline">
                <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                    <active xmi:value="false"/>
                    <stopped xmi:value="false"/>
                    <multiObject xmi:value="false"/>
                    <lifeline/>
                    <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                </xmi:Extension>
                <coveredBy xmi:idref="n0XgQGqAUEBg4gsE"/>
            </lifeline>
            <ownedAttribute name="inventory" xmi:id="mdyff6qAUEBg4ggL_represents"/>
            <lifeline name=" Book_price" represents="WeRQ_6qAUEBg4ggW_represents" xmi:id="WeRQ_6qAUEBg4ggW" xmi:type="uml:Lifeline">
                <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                    <active xmi:value="false"/>
                    <stopped xmi:value="false"/>
                    <multiObject xmi:value="false"/>
                    <lifeline/>
                    <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                </xmi:Extension>
                <coveredBy xmi:idref="auR_gGqAUEBg4gnl"/>
            </lifeline>
            <ownedAttribute name=" Book_price" xmi:id="WeRQ_6qAUEBg4ggW_represents"/>

            <ownedConnector xmi:id="5FbGQGqAUEBg4gw." xmi:type="uml:Connector">
                <end role="3cGo_6qAUEBg4gkc" xmi:id="5FbGQGqAUEBg4gw_" xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd">
                    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                        <modelType value="InteractionLifeLineLinkEnd"/>
                        <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                    </xmi:Extension>
                </end>
                <end role="Z2TGQGqAUEBg4gw5" xmi:id="5FbGQGqAUEBg4gxA" xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd">
                    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                        <modelType value="InteractionLifeLineLinkEnd"/>
                        <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                    </xmi:Extension>
                </end>
                <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                    <modelType value="InteractionLifeLineLink"/>
                    <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                </xmi:Extension>
                <ownedRule constrainedElement="2SnGQGqAUEBg4gxK" name="Gift" xmi:id="1Cq2QGqAUEBg4gyh">
                    <specification body="(r&gt;10) ^ (x*r=&lt;200)" xmi:type="uml:OpaqueExpression"/>
                    <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                        <qualityScore value="-1"/>
                    </xmi:Extension>
                </ownedRule>
            </ownedConnector>

            <ownedAttribute name="Actor" xmi:id="nEWmv6qAUEBg4gWa_represents"/>
            <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
                <qualityScore value="-1"/>
            </xmi:Extension>
        </ownedBehavior>
    </ownedMember>
    <ownedMember name="entity" xmi:id="InteractionLifeLine_entity_id" xmi:type="uml:Stereotype">
        <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
            <baseType value="InteractionLifeLine"/>
            <qualityScore value="-1"/>
        </xmi:Extension>
    </ownedMember>
    <ownedMember name="boundary" xmi:id="InteractionLifeLine_boundary_id" xmi:type="uml:Stereotype">
        <xmi:Extension extender="Visual Paradigm">
            <baseType value="InteractionLifeLine"/>
            <qualityScore value="-1"/>
        </xmi:Extension>
    </ownedMember>
</uml:Model>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh at last , I found this solution, If you want to read XMI 1.0 and 1.2 version files you can download code from give below and can generate hierarchy view and code of XMI model as well.

[XMI Read with C# and generate Hierarchy and Code of XMI Model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13034/Xmi-CodeDom-Library-Part)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XDocument to read xml file in C# and then store it into a custom class.

Now you have the flexibility to save it into database by iterating it.

```
  public CatSubCatList GenerateCategoryListFromProductFeedXML()
    {
        string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_xmlFilePath);

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

        XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(xDoc.ToString());


        List<Category> lstCategory = xElement.Elements("Product").Select(d => new Category
        {
            Code = Convert.ToString(d.Element("CategoryCode").Value),
            CategoryPath = d.Element("CategoryPath").Value,
            Name = GetCateOrSubCategory(d.Element("CategoryPath").Value, 0), // Category
            SubCategoryName = GetCateOrSubCategory(d.Element("CategoryPath").Value, 1) // Sub Category
        }).GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.SubCategoryName }).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

        CatSubCatList catSubCatList = GetFinalCategoryListFromXML(lstCategory);

        return catSubCatList;
    }
```